# VBA can someone guide me why my object library missing getelementsbyClassName?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to scrap a webpage. I have already ticked 
Microsoft Object lib and Microsoft XML v6.0

*my VBA object browser*
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're missing more than getelementsbyClassName. getelementsbyTagNameNS, getSelection, HasAttributes are also missing. Did you reference Microsoft HTML Object Library to include them or some other reference?

Comment: Yes I referenced MS HTML obj lib. guys please help

Comment: Perhaps you have an older version of the library, one that was designed for earlier versions of Internet Explorer. If you have an older machine and don't use IE, perhaps you never bothered to update it. Things like Fire Fox will have their own DOM library. It couldn't hurt to see what happens if you update to the newest version of IE.